# Parent Acitivity's status not kept when backing from child activity

Tags: android-activity, navigation

In AndroidManifext.xml, I have :

```
        <activity
            android:name=".mypackage.ChildActivity"
            android:label="Child"
            android:parentActivityName=".mypackage.ParentActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".view.activities.ParentActivity" />
        </activity>
```

Inside ParentActivity, I have a few fragements, A, B, C. At fragment C, I launch ChildActivity when clicking a button. When backing to ParentActivity, I am not landing on Fragment C, but Fragment A. It appears that ParentActivity is relaunched or initialized again.

In ChildActivity, I have:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

As a comparison, I also tried to replace ChildActivity with a Fragment D and backing from fragment D correctly lands on fragment C.

Where did I miss for the ChildActivity implementation?

**Edited:**
Just noticed that when clicking "Back" button on device, it properly backs to Fragment C of ParentActivity, but if hitting the "<" button at the left top corner in Child Activity, that's where issue arises.

Thanks in advance!

Shawn

Answer (score 0):

Remove the mentioning parent from your childActivity. Like below. Because android already maintains the stack of navigations

```
<activity
            android:name=".mypackage.ChildActivity"
            android:label="Child"
            android:parentActivityName=".mypackage.ParentActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
</activity>
```

Comment: I want that "<" button shown at the left top corner of ChildActivity so that I have to keep the ParentActivity in the AndroidManifest.xml, It seems that the issue is in "onOptionsItemSelected()" where I just simply call onBackPressed() to make the "<" behave same as clicking the "Back" button in device.